# does @ symbol has any significance in solidity?

Tags: solidity, blockchain

In hyperledger when @ symbol is used in comments and it has its significance and is required before defining a function. I was going through some solidity code examples and I saw this piece of code

```
/**
* @title Ownable
* @dev 
*/
```

so does that @ has any use or significance?

Answer (score 4):

These are "NatSpec" comments. The [Solidity documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/layout-of-source-files.html#comments) has this to say:

> Additionally, there is another type of comment called a natspec
>   comment, for which the documentation is not yet written. They are
>   written with a triple slash (`///`) or a double asterisk block(`/** ... */`) and they should be used directly above function declarations or statements. You can use Doxygen-style tags inside these comments to
>   document functions, annotate conditions for formal verification, and
>   provide a confirmation text which is shown to users when they attempt
>   to invoke a function.

The wiki has a bit more about them: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Natural-Specification-Format.

I'm not sure which tools actually consume these comments, but hopefully that documentation will get you started in learning more.

Comment: Deleted my answers as yours is clearly more correct :-) Looks like this tool at least can consume it: https://github.com/DigixGlobal/doxity

Answer (score 2):

It's not something that is required before defining a function.

The [solidity compiler uses](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layout-of-source-files.html?highlight=natspec#comments) [doxygen-style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doxygen) NatSpec tags inside comments to *optionally* document functions, annotate conditions for formal verification, and provide a confirmation text that is shown to users when they attempt to invoke a function.

The different [types of tags are](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Natural-Specification-Format#tags):

- `@title`
- `@author`
- `@notice`
- `@dev`
- `@param`
- `@return`